# Translate a HTML template page with WPML Wordpress Plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, wpml

On my website I have made a page in HTML, which I have made for a template. It works fine, but how do I translate it into another language?

I have looked under "Strings" but can not find anything ...

Comment: I had made a HTML page from scratch, and I would like this HMTL page to be a landing page on my website. I insert it into a new file in Wordpress, and insert the following PHP code: <? Php / * Template Name: myTemplateName * /?>

I can activate my temple, and it seems as it should. All I have to figure out is how I translate my template into another language. Anyone who knows how to do? I have used the WPML Wordpress plugin for the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first completely convert HTML to WordPress, so you can use the multilingual plugin.
Be sure to make the files **index.php** , **style.css** Make the code for the Css in the first css so that the plugin can recognize the plugin.
Then you need functions **wp_head()** in head in header.php and **wp_footer()** in footer.php